# Issue Angular-Meteor Meteor.publishComposite

Tags: meteor, publish, angular-meteor

When running `helper` brings values are stored in the variable `verCandidatos.postulados`.

Once I get me the information I need to get a document that is linked (using the function `ng-init="candidato = la postulado.candidato()`) wich runs on the  `helper` from file: `collection.js`.

Sometimes the `html` shows the properties: `{{candidato.nombre}}`, `{{candidato.apellidos}}` and `{{candidato.sexo}}` correctly, and sometimes appear empty, **why?**

Is very strange, like a `bug` or something. How is possible that behavior?

The information is being obtained, because the `ng-repeat` works and shows elements.

Below is the publishComposite(), collection.js,  `html` and `js` client

**html client**

**my-app/imports/ui/components/vacantes/verCandidatos/** verCandidatos.html

```
<div ng-repeat="postulado in verCandidatos.postulados">
    <div ng-init="candidato = postulado.candidato();">
          {{candidato.nombre}} 
          {{candidato.apellidos}}
          {{candidato.sexo}}            
    </div>
</div>
```

**js in client**

**my-app/imports/ui/components/vacantes/verCandidatos/** verCandidatos.js

```
imports ...  


class VerCandidatos {
    constructor($scope, $reactive, $stateParams) {
        'ngInject';
        $reactive(this).attach($scope);
        this.vacanteId = $stateParams.vacanteId;
        this.subscribe('vacantes.candidatosOseleccionados', ()=> [{vacanteId: this.vacanteId}, {estado: 1}]);
        this.helpers({
            postulados (){
                return Postulaciones.find();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**collection.js**

**my-app/imports/api/postulaciones/** collection.js

```
imports...

export const Postulaciones = new Mongo.Collection('postulaciones');

Postulaciones.deny({...});

Postulaciones.helpers({
    candidato(){
        return Candidatos.findOne({_id: this.candidatoId});
  }  
});
```

**publish.js:**

**my-app/imports/api/vacantes/server/** publish.js

```
imports...

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.publishComposite('vacantes.candidatosOseleccionados', function (vacanteId, estado) {
        const selector = {$and: [estado, vacanteId]};
            return {
                find: function () {
                    return Postulaciones.find(selector);
                },
                children: [
                    {
                        find: function (postulacion) {
                            return Candidatos.find({_id: postulacion.candidatoId}, {
                                fields: {
                                    nombre: 1,
                                    apellidos: 1,
                                    sexo: 1,
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                ]
            };
    });
}
```

**Any ideas?**
- Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The `ISSUE` was in `html`
The solution was deteted `ng-init` and call directly the `helpers` inside `collection.js`, the other files `(js in client`,   `collection.js`,  `publish.js`) aren't modify.

The  `html` file is as follows:

```
<div ng-repeat="postulado in verCandidatos.postulados">
      {{postulado.candidato().nombre}}
      {{postulado.candidato().apellidos}}
      {{postulado.candidato().sexo}}            
</div>
```

Thanks for read. 
And I hope you will be useful.